# How can I get custom image folder's name in iOS?

Tags: ios, react-native

Thanks in advance to read this question.

I want to get a list of 'Custom image folder' in iOS, to make multi image selecting function.
I figured out how to show all the images in a list, but in every image node, group_name is 'All photos'... so I couldn't sort images.
How can I get each image's folder name?

Actually I'm using react-native, but Objective-C answer is also no problem...

p.s. I'm not trying to save pictures, just getting folder name is my interest.